# How I Can Access Current Logged In User Details & Shipping Information In Shopify Checkout UI Extension

Tags: shopify-app

guys I am in a problem where I am facing an issue with capturing customer & shipping information at checkout UI extension where there is a checkbox if the user checked this checkbox this information need to be sent to our backend which is hosted on AWS using Django & Graphql Servers. Here is the code snippet of the extension/index.jsx file. and I deployed this to the Shopify development store where UI is rendered but I have no idea after this how to capture user & shipping info when the user successfully placed the order with the brand's checkout page and when the checkbox is checked.

Snippet:https://carbon.now.sh/ZNrFMxAZk9GXw7nUo5W0

```
import React from 'react';
import {
useExtensionApi,
render,
Grid,
GridItem,
Heading,
Checkbox,
View,
BlockSpacer,
Text,
Link,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {
const {extensionPoint} = useExtensionApi();
return <View border="base" padding={"base"} borderRadius="base">
<Grid columns={['95%','5%']}>
<GridItem>
<Heading>Declutter your closet and get 15% off on your next order.</Heading>
</GridItem>
<GridItem>
<Checkbox/>
</GridItem>
</Grid>

<Text>Schedule a free doorstep pickup and get rid if the clothes that you no longer want,need or fit-into.</Text>
<BlockSpacer/>
<Link to="https://phirlo.in">Learn how?</Link>
</View>;
}
```